# Error in PHP function

Tags: php, exec, printf, ping

I have this little script, which should ping the IPs in the `$hosts_to_ping` array. This PHP is called with JavaScript in the index.html.

But something is wrong, because the `$rval` is always 1 (which mean the host is unreachable). But I know that the first two host are alive.

So I print the `$res` variable, and I see the message: `Need to give the IP`. I don't understand why it doesn't replace the `$host` variable to the actual IP address in the function.

```
<?php
  function ping($host) {
  exec(sprintf('ping -n 4', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
    print_r($res);
    return $rval === 0;
  }

  $hosts_to_ping = array('10.54.23.254', '10.22.23.254', '10.23.66.134');
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($hosts_to_ping as $host): ?>
  <li>
  <?php echo $host; ?>
  <?php $up = ping($host); ?>

    (<img src="<?php echo $up ? 'on' : 'off'; ?>"
          alt="<?php echo $up ? 'up' : 'down'; ?>">)
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line:

```
  exec(sprintf('ping -n 4', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
```

[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) won't interpolate `escapeshellarg($host)` in the string because you missed the *%s*. Replace that line with:

```
  exec(sprintf('ping -n 4 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
```

Try this and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't replace anything in your sprintf. It probably should look like this to make it work : `exec(sprintf('ping -n 4 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);`