# php ping test and redirect

Tags: php, redirect, ip, ping, host

I am trying to get a basic php ping script working that will ping my sites ip and if it responds will redirect the user to my site however if it doesn't it will redirect the user elsewhere. I've attached what I have so far below however currently it does not appear to be pinging the site as it just goes straight to http://othersite.com as show in the example below. Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
<?php

function ping($host)
{
    exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
    return $rval === 0;
}
// random host ip example
$host = '8.8.8.8';
$online = ping($host);

// if site is online, send them to the site.
if( $online ) {
       header('Location: mysite.com');
} 
// otherwise, lets go elsewhere to an online site
else {
        header('Location: http://othersite.com/');
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you aware of the  different output? when pinging from a Linux machine? and Windows machine? if so, then capture your output then act on a key phrase, so your script can recognize a success or failure

Comment: I didn't think of that its a linux vps that im pinging I'll revise the script based on that thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Your code seems to work fine on Linux but not on windows. Checking a little further I noticed that windows does not provide `-c` option for ping, which causes it to return a different value than expected and your ping fails

```
exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
    return $rval === 0;
```

That seems to assume that the return value will be `0` from `exec` on success? But according to [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) it will be

`The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function. 
To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter.`

It appears like your comparison with returned value is the problem. What value does `$rval` contain?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll look at your suggestions and try to make it work based on them. I'm new to working with php but I assumed that the $rval should return either a 0 or a 1 based on wether the host is online or not I used some of the code from this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880255/php-function-problem">question</a> to write it. Thank you again for your help :)